# How to increment build version in xcode with date and constant

Tags: xcode, bash, build, increment

I want change my bundle version like this standart - N1.79-14.11.2014
When N is permanent, 1.79 - increment when i archive project. I find solution only for date part. I use this code - https://gist.github.com/alokc83/5207294

How i can parse string for increment build number at this case?

OR Just increment N1.79 + 0.01.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution for "N1.90" format variant.

https://gist.github.com/shevyakov-nikolay/c87cd9841279985d64b1